# Using Chart.js, How can I create a bar chart for several sets of data

Tags: graph, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, data-representation

I am trying to create an advanced bar chart using chart.js.  I would like my chart to have 3 sets of 3 bars.  Each set examines data over a different time interval (7 days, 14 days, 30 days).  I have attached the source data along with the image of the type of chart I wish to create.  I have been able to create this graph in Google sheets, but was wondering if this can be created in chart.js.  Thank you for the help.

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilRRm.jpg)
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTtLM.jpg)

Comment: Yes you can create it

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to figure this out!